# Does a fully faithful functor always preserve limits and colimits?

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

I read on [this n-lab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/full+and+faithful+functor) that a fully faithful functor $F: C\to D$ reflects all limits and colimits by the universal property.

On the other hand, I think a fully faithful functor does not always preserve limits and colimits since a "testing object" in $D$ is not necessarily in the image of $F$.

Are there any easy counter examples?

Comment: What your concern points at is that limits and colimits are not necessarily _preserved_ by a fully faithful functor.

Comment: I provide an explicit counterexample to a fully faithful functor preserving limits in my answer

Comment: In fact, I'd say that it's relatively _rare_ for a fully faithful functor $F: \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ to preserve both limits and colimits. After all, if things are nice enough so that adjoint functor theorems can be applied everywhere, and if $F$ preserves both limits and colimits, then $F$ admits both a left and a right adjoint, $\mathcal C$ is simultaneously a reflective and coreflective subcategory of $\mathcal D$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The forgetful functor from abelian groups to groups is fully faithful, and does not preserve coproducts. For example, in abelian groups, $\mathbb Z\coprod \mathbb Z=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$, but in groups $\mathbb Z\coprod \mathbb Z$ is the free group on two generators.

Answer (score 9):

The point is that the cone starts out in $C$, then you test it in $D$.
Being a limit cone in $D$ is *more* than you need by virtue of what you mentioned about some test objects in $D$ not being visible to $F$.

Suppose you had a cone $\ell$ in $C$ whose image under $F$ is a limit cone in $D$. Let $c$ be another cone in $C$ for the same diagram, then $Fc$ will be a cone in $D$ and so by the universal property (of $F\ell$ in $D$) this admits a unique morphism $Fc\to F\ell$.
Now, since $F$ is fully faithful, this morphism arises as a unique morphism $c\to\ell$ in $C$, proving that $\ell$ has the universal property of being a limit cone in $C$ as well.

I suspect you might be confusing this with the property of [preserving](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preserved+limit) limits. If a fully faithful functor cannot see all the objects of $D$ (i.e., is not essentially surjective) then the fact that there are test objects in $D$ that $F$ cannot see will make it possible that a limit cone in $C$ will no longer be a limit cone in $D$.

For an explicit example, let $C=\{0\}$ be a one object category, and $D=\{0\to1\}$ the walking arrow category. Take $F:C\to D$ to be the inclusion sending $0\mapsto0$, then $F$ is fully faithful. However, $0$ is a limit cone for the empty diagram in $C$ (since it is the terminal object), but $F(0)=0$ is *not* a limit cone for the empty diagram in $D$.

Comment: The problem is that not all cones in $D$ are of the form $Fc$.

Comment: When you're talking about _reflecting_ limits, you only care about cones that come from $C$. What you know is that the image of $\ell$ is a limit cone in $D$, so fully faithfulness allows you to move the problem to $D$ (where you know by assumption that there is a factoring morphism) and then bring it back to $C$.

Comment: Reflecting limits means that "cones in $C$ that are limits in $D$ become limits in $C$"

Comment: Reflecting limits means that "cones in $C$ that are limits in $C$ become limits in $D$".

Comment: Let $l$ be a limit cone in $C$. Although for any cone $c$ in $C$, there is a unique morphism $Fc\to F l$, this does not mean that for any cone $d$ in $D$ there is a unique morphism $d\to F l$ since $d$ is not necessarily of the form $Fc$.

Comment: In the definition of a [reflected limit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflected+limit), we have that $F$ reflects limits if $\ell$ is a limit in $C$ whenever $F\ell$ is a limit in $D$. In particular, this means that when testing if $F$ reflects limits, you are already assuming that _any cone_ $d$ in $D$ admits a unique factoring morphism $d\to F\ell$. We then only care about those cones of the form $Fc$ for some cone $c$ in $C$.

Comment: What you are doing is the opposite, which is regarding the property of [preserving](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preserved+limit) a limit. You're correct that a limit cone $\ell$ in $C$ is _not necessarily_ a limit cone $F\ell$ in $D$ even if $F$ is fully faithful, but I even provide an example of this in my answer.

Comment: It seems that I misunderstand the term "preserve". I will modify my question. Thank you.